# hapi joi how to validate Optional parameters

Tags: hapi.js, joi

How to validate an optional parameter
using hapi and joi

```
path: '/users/{limit?}',
```

limit is optional but if present should be an integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Joi.number().integer()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi#numberinteger) in the `validate` section:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path:'/users/{limit?}',
    config: {
        validate: {
            params: {
                limit: Joi.number().integer()
            }
        }
    },
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('ok');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I don't use require the field is validate only if present ? (I can't try it now)

Comment: Exactly. I tested the code before submitted my answer. Valid: `/users`, `/users/1`, invalid: `/users/a`, `/users/3.14`.